# How to fix NoClassDefFoundError: org.slf4j.LoggerFactory in intelliJ (but eclipse works fine)

Tags: java, eclipse, intellij-idea, slf4j

Eclipse runs my code fine (right click -> run ), yet when I try to run the same exact project and main method in intellij, I get this error. Is there a way to see where eclipse is getting the dependencies from and replicate adding those in Intellij?

I've tried switching the API from provided to runtime.... then I get a different issue - not able to finds the proper LoggerFactory type.. Yet eclipse finds the dependency just fine.

These are in my pom hierarchy:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
  <artifactId>log4j-slf4j-impl</artifactId>
  <version>2.11.1</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
  <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
</dependency>

    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.slf4j.LoggerFactory
at com.railroad.messaging.consoleapp.PumpEmpMessagetoQpid.<clinit>(PumpEmpMessagetoQpid.java:16)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.slf4j.LoggerFactory
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:609)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassHelper(ClassLoader.java:926)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:871)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:343)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:854)
... 1 more
```

Comment: There is an option to refresh/rebuild maven project in idea. You will find a tab in the right hand side, it is maven. Click on maven and you will find a refresh icon. Just click it.

Comment: That doesn't fix it. I think the IDE needs to locate the Logger implementation at runtime...

Comment: I have the same issue with a Spring Boot App in Intellij, eclipse is working fine as well as compiled everything is working great. Just when trying to run it from intellij it won't run without me adding these dependencies explicitely:
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
   <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.yaml</groupId>
   <artifactId>snakeyaml</artifactId>
  </dependency>

Answer (score 2):

Check your parent project pom.xml. May be you need to remove scope "provided" in slf4j dependency block (in PARENT project).

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId
    <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
    <version>${slf4.version}</version>        

    <!-- DELETE THIS ROW: -->
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution was to add the slf4j entries in the dependency management section.

```
  <dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.36</version>
      </dependency>

      <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.17</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-reload4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.36</version>
      </dependency>
    </dependencies>
  </dependencyManagement>
```